# Smarty syntax error when compiling html with zero width space character (&#8203)

Tags: php, html, smarty

In chrome browser, CKEdtor inserts the zero-width-space(&#8203), so when we save that database(I am using MySql database with UTF8 char set) it is saving '?' in database. When compiling the html saved previously with smarty template engine, it is throwing error:

> Unexpected "�" Syntax Error in template "e42c92a1f0b93326a41cb5c43113967a3f688239" on line 26 "

How to filter these type of characters from being injected?

Comment: have you set the meta preperly? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: I tried that but,still it is coming

Comment: Syntax Error in template ""7b5db08cd6b079a0646b84c851edd004bdfdf0d1""  on line 27 ""&lt;td style=&quot;vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap;&quot;&gt;{if $RECORD.hdnDiscountPercent​ &lt; 3}test1{else}test2{/if}&lt;/td&gt;""  - Unexpected ""�"""